# Animate multiple elemts from middle to top with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-ajax

i'm trying to move  divs(actually they are [AlwaysVisibleControls](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AlwaysVisibleControl/AlwaysVisibleControl.aspx)) from center-screen to the top of the page after a few seconds.

This is what i have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded)
});

var ScrollTopTimeOuts = [];
function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
    $('.PanelNotificationBox').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    while (ScrollTopTimeOuts.length != 0) {
        clearTimeout(ScrollTopTimeOuts[ScrollTopTimeOuts.length - 1]);
        ScrollTopTimeOuts.length--;
    }
    ScrollTopTimeOuts[ScrollTopTimeOuts.length] = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.PanelNotificationBox').animate({ top: 0 }, 'slow');
    }, 3000);
}
```

This works, but the problem is that there can be more than one notification(`$('.PanelNotificationBox').size()>1`). Then they will overlap each other after the animation.

**Q:** How can i animate elements so that the first element will be on top and the next elements will keep their positions relative to the others?

**Edit**: After i added the notification-div(s) to a container-div and try to animate that, it won't be animated at all. This is the generated HTML/CSS(note: the outer div is an UpdatePanel):

```
<div id="ctl00_UpdNotifier"         
    <div style="top: 0px;" id="ctl00_Notifier1_PnlNotification" class="NotificationContainer">
        <div style="left: 292px; top: 398px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" id="ctl00_Notifier1_InfoMsg2" class="PanelNotificationBox PanelInfo AutoHide" title="click to close notification">
            <span>Test-Notification(Info)</span>
        </div>
        <div style="left: 292px; top: 463px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" id="ctl00_Notifier1_ErrorMsg1" class="PanelNotificationBox PanelError" title="click to close notification">
            <span>Test-Notification(RMA-Error)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-File:

```
.PanelNotificationBox 
{
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:9999;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:small;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #3A4F63;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.PanelInfo {
    color:Black;
    background-color: InfoBackground;
    background-image: url('../images/info-icon.png');
}

.PanelError {
    color:White;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('../images/error-icon.png');
}
```

Comment: Is a wrapper element possible? I mean, you could put all notifications in one wrapper element, and only move that. This way the relative position could be handled with css only.

Comment: @Yoshi: I'm generating the notification-divs from codebehind, it wouldn't be a problem to add them to a container-div instead. I will try it.

Comment: @Yoshi: if i add them to a wrapper and animate that, they won't move at all. I think that is because of the `position:absolute` of the `AlwaysVisibleControl-Extender`.

Comment: Can you show some of the rendered html/css?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to place all your messages in a div, and set this div on abosule position on the top of the page and animate this div that holds all the messages. I think that you can even just place all your element in this div, and they arrange by him self the one afther the other.

```
<style type="text/css">
.Containerv {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:230px;    
}   
</style>

<div id="ContainerID" class="Container">
    <div>First element</div>
    <div>Second element</div>   
    <div>.... next elements</div>
</div>
```

and your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded)
});

var ScrollTopTimeOuts = [];
function PageLoaded(sender, args) 
{
    // keep this to indivitual close messages
    $('.PanelNotificationBox').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

   clearTimeout(ScrollTopTimeOuts);

   ScrollTopTimeOuts = setTimeout(function () {
       $('#ContainerID').animate({ top: 0 }, 'slow');
   }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. But a wrapper control was needless. jQuery's `each` function and the distance of the first div from the top of the page  was [all i need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119270/animate-multiple-elemts-from-middle-to-top-with-jquery/8121221#8121221) ;)

Comment: @Tim I came up with this idea, because you ask how to place them inside something to be the one ather the other, and its less complex. How ever the adding the offset is nice idea also.

Answer (score 0):

The approaches from @Yoshi and @Aristos had the disadvatage of breaking the `AlwaysVisibleControls` js-functionality. Thank you anyway :)

I ended with this solution what is working fine(leaving out the timer part):

```
var first=$('.PanelNotificationBox:first');
$('.PanelNotificationBox').each(function (index) {
    $(this).animate({ top: '-=' + first.offset().top }, 'slow');
});
```